# Dockerize a node express app with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I've got a node app that I can run locally using `npm run`. It is using express as the server and uses browser sync to show hot reloads.

Express is using port `6001`
Browsersync is using ports `3000` and `3001`

**Docker file**

```
FROM node/argon

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

USER app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN sudo chown -R app /usr/src/app
RUN npm start
EXPOSE 6001
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-base.yml
    service: web
  ports:
    - "6001:6001"
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: testing.docker
```

**docker-compose-base.yml**

```
web: 
  build: .
  command: npm start
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

I can run `docker-compose build` and it builds just fine, running `docker-compose up` spits out the following:

```
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------
 Local: http://localhost:3000
 ----------------------------
    UI: http://localhost:3001
 ----------------------------
Listening on http://localhost:6001
```

But accessing `http://testing.docker` appears as though the container never mounted. Running `docker-compose ps` shows no containers, but running `docker ps` shows the container is available.

I'm completely at a loss.

Comment: Did you use `docker-compose up` to start the containers?

Comment: Yes, that's what generated the "listening" logs.

Comment: Try `docker-compose up -d` and then `docker-compose ps` in that directory, as well as `docker ps` to see if they return anything. Also try `curl localhost:6001` to check if port mapping is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a key part of the equation here: I am using dinghy to manage the containers and it needs a port to forward to.

So that changes the files to look like this:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node/argon

RUN echo 08-03-2016 > last_docker_cache_bust

EXPOSE 6001

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .npmrc* /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

ADD . /usr/src/app
RUN sudo chown -R app /usr/src/app
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-base.yml
    service: web
  ports:
    # The first port is managed by dinghy, the second is the app's running port for express
    - "7510:6001"
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: testing.docker
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have "testing.docker" host entry set up somewhere your browser can resolve, change the format for that entry to:

```
environment:
  - VIRTUAL_HOST=testing.docker
```

You would also need to expose ports 3000 and 3001 to get the browser-sync working:

```
ports:
  - "6001:6001"
  - "3000:3000"
  - "3001:3001"
```

And as mentioned, use `docker-compose up -d` if you want to detach the containers to run them in the background. If you are quitting the output in the same terminal window as you are checking `docker-compose ps` and not detaching, the containers will not be running. If you do check in a separate window, make sure you are in the right directory and/or using a `--project-name` in your compose commands.

Comment: I think normally your solution would work, however there was a key component missing in this - I forgot about the fact that I'm using dinghy.